# VBA как вставить формулу в последний столбец и притянуть ее?

Tags: vba

есть такая формула

```
Range("Db23:Db" & Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row).FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=VLOOKUP(RC[" & -(lastCol - Col_KD + 1) & "],'*путь к файлу*'!C3:C6,4,0)"
```

Как вместо "Db23:Db" поставить диапазон первого пустого столбца в строке 23?

Comment: Пробую так, но не работает Range(Cells(23, Cells(23, 23).End(xlToRight).Column + 1), Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row).FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=VLOOKUP(RC[" & -(lastCol - Col_KD + 1) & "],'[путь к файлу'!C3:C6,4,0)"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Лепить все в одну кучу - плохое решение. Код нечитабельный, себе же на потом готовите головную боль

```
Dim StartRow As Long, LastRow As Long, LastColumn As Long

StartRow = 22

With Worksheets("sheet1")
    LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    LastColumn = .Cells(23, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    
    .Cells(StartRow, LastColumn + 1).Resize(LastRow - StartRow + 1, 1).FormulaLocal = "=formula"
End With
```